# Text in PDF exported from QGIS cannot be edited in Illustrator

Tags: qgis-3

The latest update of QGIS is amazing. A big problem persists: I cannot edit text in an exported PDF in Illustrator.

When I export to PDF, I have the option to export text as text objects turned on. I can edit the text in Acrobat, but it’s not as good as Illustrator for making adjustments. The problem is that every typeface I use in QGIS brings up the Missing Fonts dialog in Illustrator, even for the most common, such as Arial.

Furthermore, every letter becomes individual; there are no longer words.

This doesn’t happen from any other program I use regularly (Word and InDesign), even if I use less-common fonts that I might expect to cause a problem.

Has anyone experienced this? Does anyone have an insight into how I might fix the problem?

Comment: svg preserves font text. convert in Illustrator to ai or pdf